# Is it possible to upload a file without user's action or just a dialog box in html, angular?

Tags: java, html, angular, spring-boot

I have a web application where users can upload files. So I want to know if it's possible if a user picks a file to upload then closes the browser, to get back this same file and upload it directly without user action or just a dialog box to confirm, after the user comes back to the application.

I already thought about local storage but i can't store images usually exceeding the limit of 10 MB. But i don't know if storing the path of the file with local storage will enable me to direct upload it after by using the path stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If storing the path of the file with local storage will enable me to
>   direct upload it after by using the path stored

You cant use the path in the local storage to upload the file.You can't do this without user intervention,which would be a huge security hole. Think about visiting a web page and it being able to grab and upload any of your files without you doing a thing.

Comment: Going through the input type="file" to upload something is mandatory you think ? So is it impossible to resume automatically an upload after closing then going back to the web application ?

Comment: Yes with the web , it is impossible. But when it comes to desktop apps you can use socket programming and other ways to achieve this.